# KeyError When Creating New Column from GroupBy Operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to create a new column by performing some operations on the existing columns but it is throwing a key error in my code. I tried to debug it by using df.columns and copy pasted the exact names but still I got the same error. My code is as follows:

```
def calculate_elasticity(group):
    sales_change = group['Primary Sales Quantity'].pct_change()
    price_change = group['MRP'].pct_change()
    
    elasticity = sales_change / price_change
    
    return elasticity

df['Variant-based Elasticity'] = df.groupby('Variant').transform(calculate_elasticity)
```

The error shown is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

16 frames
pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Primary Sales Quantity'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'Primary Sales Quantity'
```

I tried to debug and following is the result of df.columns
`Index(['Cal. year / month', 'Material', 'Product Name', 'MRP', 'Distribution Channel  (Master)', 'Unnamed: 5', 'L1 Prod Category', 'L2 Prod Brand', 'L3 Prod Sub-Category', 'State', 'Primary Actual GSV  Value', 'Primary Sales Qty (CS)', 'Secondary GSV', 'Secondary sales Qty(CS)', 'Primary Volume(MT/KL)', 'Secondary Volume(MT/KL)', 'Variant', 'Weight', 'Offers', 'Primary Sales Quantity'], dtype='object')`

and result to `print(df['Primary Sales Quantity'])` is

```
0          155
1        16953
2          455
3          138
4         2653
         ...  
14147        6
14148        1
14149     8428
14150      237
14151       24
Name: Primary Sales Quantity, Length: 14152, dtype: int64
```

I tried to debug using the column names. I can even access the column by that name just the error is thrown in this function.

Comment: The traceback doesn't show the calling code

Comment: **pandas KeyError = don't have column**, The reason you are getting an error is because the 'Primary Sales Quantity' column does not exist in the `group`  in function. (even if that column exists in `df`)  To confirm this, you can add a `print(group)`  above `sales_change = group['Primary Sales Quantity'].pct_change()`.  result of `print(group)` is Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) is not possible processing 2 columns together, need [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
def calculate_elasticity(group):
    sales_change = group['Primary Sales Quantity'].pct_change()
    price_change = group['MRP'].pct_change()
    
    group['Variant-based Elasticity'] = sales_change / price_change
    return group

df = df.groupby('Variant', group_keys=False).apply(calculate_elasticity)
print (df)
  Variant  Primary Sales Quantity  MRP  Variant-based Elasticity
0       a                      10    8                       NaN
1       a                       7   10                 -1.200000
2       b                      87    3                       NaN
3       b                       8    2                  2.724138
```

Or change solution without helper function:

```
g = df.groupby('Variant')
df['Variant-based Elasticity'] = (g['Primary Sales Quantity'].pct_change() /
                                  g['MRP'].pct_change())
print (df)
  Variant  Primary Sales Quantity  MRP  Variant-based Elasticity
0       a                      10    8                       NaN
1       a                       7   10                 -1.200000
2       b                      87    3                       NaN
3       b                       8    2                  2.724138
```

Alternative solution with helper `df1` DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Variant')[['Primary Sales Quantity', 'MRP']].pct_change()
df['Variant-based Elasticity'] = df1['Primary Sales Quantity'] / df1['MRP']
print (df)
  Variant  Primary Sales Quantity  MRP  Variant-based Elasticity
0       a                      10    8                       NaN
1       a                       7   10                 -1.200000
2       b                      87    3                       NaN
3       b                       8    2                  2.724138
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variant': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                   'Primary Sales Quantity': [10, 7, 87, 8], 
                   'MRP': [8, 10, 3, 2]})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually used apply before but it was also throwing some type error. but thanks for the other code. that worked perfectly fine! also thanks for the info that transform can't process two columns together.

Comment: i think `group_keys=False` needed in your first answer block. Of course, I think the second and third answers are more valuable.

Comment: @FaizAbbasSyed kindly accept the answer if it solved your issue. It helps others too to quickly find out the correct resolution as well as the author of the answer